# Access VBA Combobox Store Value in Column

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have an MS ACCESS Combo Box and I wish to change the value of one of the columns in a particular row.  I get error "object required" when I run this line:

Me.ComboName.Column(12, intUseRow) = myVar

(If I am unable to use the above syntax then you should also know that the row I am trying to change is always going to be the "current" visible row so there may be another way of solving the problem due to this fact).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have this in a class module or new module?

Comment: There are three ways to populate an MS Access combo box: 1) use a table, query or sql string; 2) use a delimited list; or 3) use a callback function. These methods do not allow you to change values in the list as per what you're attempting. ComboBox.Column is readonly! Could you detail your scenario and perhaps I can show you a way forward?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recordset that is bound to a Table/Query, you will need to change the underlying data then requery the combobox to see changes.

If you load it manually (like in the form load event) and have the comboBox Row Source Type to "Value List" - you should be able to update it like this:

```
Copy all the data from the selected row into variables.  
Combobox.RemoveItem (selected index)
change the required variable to the new value.
construct the semicolon separated string for the value list entry
combobox.AddItem new-string.
```

a bit messy, but it works correctly!